# PHP - DataTables Post username from table row for a mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql, post, datatable, datatables

I am trying to add a delete button to my DataTables table, but I don't know how I can post the username of the selected row when Delete button is pressed.

Here is how the DataTables is printed:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Fullname</th>
                    <th>Class ID</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                while($listDetailsRow = mysql_fetch_array($listDetails)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="success"><?=$listDetailsRow['username']?></td>
                    <td class="info"><?=$listDetailsRow['email']?></td>
                    <td class="success"><?=$listDetailsRow['fullname']?></td>
                    <td class="info"><?=$listDetailsRow['class_id']?></td>
                    <td>
                    <form id='delete' action='deleteUser.php' method='post'>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteUser.php">
                    Delete
                    </button>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                 }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

So it is printed by php until all has been printedm then it stops...

The deleteUsers.php file is as follows:

```
include('../details.php');

$userDel = $_POST($listDetailsRow['username']);
echo $userDel;

// mysql_query("DELETE * FROM users WHERE username='$userDel'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I am just trying to get it to print the username from the row of which the delete button was pressed.

Is this possible? Not very good with JS or Ajax so all help is appreciated.

Comment: You never embedded any identification information in your form, so no matter WHICH button you click, you send exactly the same information each time. plus, you'll have however many DUPLICATE ids on each of those form tags, which is illegal html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id='delete' action='deleteUser.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='username' value="<?=$listDetailsRow['username'];?>" > <--add this line
 <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteUser.php">
  Delete
  </button>
  </form>
```

php:

```
$userDel = $_POST['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an a element instead of a form within a button element. See this code:

```
<tbody>

     <?php
         while($listDetailsRow = mysql_fetch_array($listDetails)){
     ?>
     <tr>
        <td class="success"><?=$listDetailsRow['username']?></td>
        <td class="info"><?=$listDetailsRow['email']?></td>
        <td class="success"><?=$listDetailsRow['fullname']?></td>
        <td class="info"><?=$listDetailsRow['class_id']?></td>
        <td>
        <!------------- New -------------->
        <?php
                $params = array( 'username' => $listDetailsRow['username'] );
                $href = "deleteUser.php?" . http_build_query($params);
          ?>
          <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo $href; ?>" > Delete </a>
          <!------------- End New -------------->
          </td>
      </tr>

                <?php
                 }
                ?>
</tbody>
```

In deleteUser.php do this:

```
$userDel = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : null;
```